# Angular 8 Response Missing _body and Headers

Tags: angular, typescript, httpresponse

Back-end code is C# in .NET targeting the 4.6.1 framework.  Front-end was recently upgraded from Angular 4 to Angular 8.  Along with that webpack went from version 2.3 to version 4.41 and typescript from 2.2 to 3.2.4.

The code itself hasn't changed.

C#:

```
public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var reject = false;
    var principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

    if (principal == null || !principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated || reject) {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
            new { error = "Unauthorized request for Impersonate Mode" },
            actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Typescript:

```
actionErrorResponseHandler(response: Response) {
    if(response.status === 401){
        if(response.text().includes("Impersonate")){
            this.displayText = ImpersonateRejectText;
        }
        this.show();
    }
}
```

(EDIT) Called like so:

```
setupPopUpModal(modalHeader: string, displayText: string){
    this.accountService.accountShowPopUpModal()
    .pipe(catchError((response: Response) => this.rejectModal.actionErrorResponseHandler(response)))
    .subscribe((result: string) => {
        if(result == "Done"){
            this.modalHeader = modalHeader;
            this.displayText = displayText;
            this.messageBoxModal.show();
        }            
    })
}
```

Previously this worked fine.  Now it generates an error that says "e.text is not a function"

If I look in Chrome's dev tools I see this from before the upgrade:

[image: Before]

And this afterwards:

[image: After]

The .text() function is trying to return the body as a string, but the body does not exist anymore.  The message I'm trying to search is now in e.error, but in Angular/Typescript "response.error" is not valid code.

I'm assuming I need to build and/or parse the response differently but I've not been able to find any documentation on this.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the part where you send the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the old Angular version was prior to 4.3 ?

With 4.3 the regular HTTP request changed from "Http" to "HttpClient". The main change is that you do not get the response as a result, but only the (json) response body.
And if the request was not a success (and a 401 isn´t one :-) ), than it errors out.

Therefor you have to catch the error and handle it. This can be done multiple ways. I would assume that you use RxJs to handle the response. Then your code may look like that

```
let response: SomeTyp;
this.httpClient.get<SomeTyp>('myBackendUrl').subscribe( (result) => response = result);
```

As a result, if your backend call returns a 400, the "regular" subscription will not be executed. Therefor `response` stays empty.

One solution could be to handle the error case in the subscribe

```
let response: SomeTyp;
this.httpClient.get<SomeTyp>('myBackendUrl').subscribe( 
  (result) => response = result,
  (errorCase) => this.handleTheError(errorCase)
);

private handleTheError(errorCase:ttpErrorResponse):void {
  if(response.status === 401){
    if(response.text().includes("Impersonate")){
      this.displayText = ImpersonateRejectText;
      return
    }
  }
  throw Error('Unexpected Backend Response');
}
```

A second solution would be to handle it in the stream

```
let response: SomeTyp;
this.httpClient.get<SomeTyp>('myBackendUrl').pipe(
  catchError( (errorCase:ttpErrorResponse) => // Handle the error )
).subscribe( 
  (result) => response = result
);
```

The advantage of "catchError" is, that you can catch the error and if it is an "expected" error that you can handle gracefully, just return a valid value. Then this value will be handled by the subscribe exactly like when you would have get a valid backend response.
If the error is NOT possible to handle gracefully, you can still throw it again

```
return throwError(errorCase);
```

And then handle it in the subscribe.

Comment: Indeed, we were on 4.0.  The HttpErrorResponse class did the trick.  Thanks!